# How to inverse transform a 3rd order difference?

Tags: python, time-series

I'm trying to create a function that will do the inverse difference for 3rd order difference of a forecasted result. Currently, I have a function that will provide the inverse transform of the 2nd difference. Is there a way for me to edit this function to do the 3rd order difference?

```
def invert_transformation(df_train, df_forecast, second_diff=False):
    """Revert back the differencing to get the forecast to original scale."""
    df_fc = df_forecast.copy()
    columns = df_train.columns
    for col in columns:        
        # Roll back 2nd Diff
        if second_diff:
            df_fc[str(col)+'_1d'] = (df_train[col].iloc[-1]-df_train[col].iloc[-2]) + df_fc[str(col)+'_2d'].cumsum()
        # Roll back 1st Diff
        df_fc[str(col)+'_forecast'] = df_train[col].iloc[-1] + df_fc[str(col)+'_1d'].cumsum()
    return df_fc
```

Comment: Yes, you have to repeat the code for "second to first" once more for "third to second".

Comment: Ok, so it would be `df_fc[str(col)+'_2d'] = (df_train[col].iloc[-2]-df_train[col].iloc[-3]) + df_fc[str(col)+'_3d'].cumsum()`  then `df_fc[str(col)+'_1d'] = (df_train[col].iloc[-1]-df_train[col].iloc[-2]) + df_fc[str(col)+'_2d'].cumsum()`. Finally...  `df_fc[str(col)+'_forecast'] = df_train[col].iloc[-1] + df_fc[str(col)+'_1d'].cumsum()`